monitor loses signal when moving program window to it (dual GPU) - happens on Windows/Linux
I have 6 monitors plugged into 2 GPUs using DisplayPort, and sometimes the monitor will lose signal when I move a window over to it. For example, I moved Firefox over and the monitor turned off (lost signal). It happens to all the monitors.
I believe it's because of dual GPU, and moving one window over to a different GPU is causing an error.
This happened on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.
My suspicions:

Cable interference of some kind (How much interference is needed before digital signals are affected?)
Physical problem with design of the 7900 XTX GPUs
Driver problems that affect both the open source Mesa driver and the Windows AMD one

Is there any way I can determine the source of the problem?
Machine specs:

GPU: 2x AMD 7900 XTX with Mesa 24.1.1 Driver (not sure the Windows
driver version)
RAM: 128GB DDR5
CPU: AMD 7950X


Power problem? PSU healthy and with enough "oomph"?

It is a 1600 watt PSU, so shouldn't have any issue.

Well, the text on the outside tells what it was supposed to be as it left the factory, yes. Strange things is known to happen after that, occasionally.
